# Downloading JSON through WebClient

Tags: c#, wpf, json, webclient

I'm trying to download a JSON from Twitter with all the authorization and stuff.

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.DownloadStringCompleted += (b, a) => {
    if (a.Cancelled)
        MessageBox.Show("Download Canceled!");
    else if (a.Error != null)
        MessageBox.Show("Download Error!");
    else
        string g = a.Result;
};
wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("TWITTER_JSON"));
```

(`TWITTER_JSON` is a long address with many authorization headers that gives the JSON)
When I run this the 2nd message ("Download Error!") shows up. Why? And how do I fix this?

Comment: What does `a.Error` contain? Would be a good starting point...

Comment: For *Download Error!* to be shown `a.Error` must contain something; that is, it's not null... so whats the exception? Instead of `MessageBox.Show("Download Error!");` put `MessageBox.Show("Download Error! " + a.Error.ToString());` and if that isn't useful try the inner exception...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a.Error is actually an Exception object. Have you tried examining it to see what the exception details contain?

```
MessageBox.Show( a.Error.ToString() );
```

That will give you more information about what actually went wrong.

You may also find it helpful to read Eric Lippert's recent blog post on [how to debug your code](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs).

Comment: Well that's your problem, you're not authorized to make the request you're trying to make. You'll need to check the documentation of the API and double-check the values you're passing along to ensure everything is correct.